# How do I go about integrating the SDK by branch.io in a Codename One app?

Tags: codenameone

We want to add a referral program using the branch.io provided [SDK](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/native-sdks-overview) within our app and I am wondering how difficult it would be to use in Codename One.

From what I know, there are currently no CN1 library that we could use for a referral program. Looking at the Codename One developer guide, there seems to be information about integrating 3rd party native SDKs, but how difficult is this to do knowing that the information in the guide is outdated? Will I need to know how to read/write in another programming language other than Java? Has the much time commitment will this be?

Answer (score 0):

The main differences between the content of the guide an the current state is the fact that SDK versions would be older and Maven is used for build.

Version numbers and small configuration flags are things you can ask about here and in reddit. The maven build makes some things simpler as iOS code goes in the iOS package.

You also have the local build now which makes integrating native code simpler and faster.

Despite that, integrating an SDK is no simple task and it's hard to evaluate the complexity beforehand. The nuances are the main stumbling blocks.

Comment: There are still a lot of grey areas for me, but please let me know if I am thinking about this correctly: 

To go through with this, I can create a single CN1 library out of the Android and iOS SDKs that Branch.io provides. And with that, detect the user's platform during runtime and use the appropriate SDK...

Is this a correct approach?

Thank you

Comment: You can create a library or just embed the native code directly in the projects respective native directories. This is detected at compile time. Only the specific native code is embedded with your project. Since you communicate with the native code via a native interface your Codename One code remains portable.